# Relation between ratio and percentage

Tags: percentages, ratio

I would like to know easiest method to solve following:

**Que:**

If $p$ is $128$% of $r$, $q$ is $96$% of $r$ and $r$ is $250$% of $s$, find the ratio of $p$:$q$:$s$.

**My Approach:**

Step 1:

$p =\frac{128r}{100}$

$q = \frac{96r}{100}$

$r = \frac{250s}{100}$

So, $s = \frac{100r}{250}$

I do not know what to do further. 
I know the answer but don't know how to achieve **Ans: $16$:$12$:$5$**

Thank You!

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly display numbers and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

- $\frac{p}{r}=\frac{128}{100}$
- $\frac{q}{r}=\frac{ 96}{100}$
- $\frac{s}{r}=\frac{100}{250}$

Adjust them to the same denominator:

- $\frac{p}{r}=\frac{128}{100}\times\frac55=\frac{640}{500}$
- $\frac{q}{r}=\frac{ 96}{100}\times\frac55=\frac{480}{500}$
- $\frac{s}{r}=\frac{100}{250}\times\frac22=\frac{200}{500}$

And you get $p:q:s=640:480:200$.

Divide each factor by their greatest common divisor ($40$).

And you get $p:q:s=640/40:480/40:200/40=16:12:5$.

Comment: Thank You for better explanation.

Comment: @divy3993: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

s is 40% of r, divide everything in units of 8% of r.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute third equation ($r = 2.5s$) into first and second equations.
That will give you ratio of p:s and q:s.

Now either substitute first equation into second or vice versa. That will give you p:q.

Last step is to make sure that the ratio's are given in integers (so for example $1:2$ instead of $\frac{1}{2} :1$). Note, you are doing it only for readability of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $p, q, r$ all depend on $s$ as follows  $$r=\frac{250}{100}\times s=\frac{250s}{100}$$ 
$$q=\frac{96}{100}\times r=\frac{96}{100}\times \frac{250s}{100}$$

$$p=\frac{128}{100}\times r=\frac{128}{100}\times \frac{250s}{100}$$ 
hence, $$\color{red}{p:q:s}=\left(\frac{128}{100}\times \frac{250s}{100}\right):\left(\frac{96}{100}\times \frac{250s}{100}\right):(s)$$ $$=128:96:40$$
$$=\color{red}{16:12:5}$$